# Read a string of 7 characters in C

Tags: c, string

I have:

```
char M[20] = "abcdabcdabcdabcd";
```

I can either print it as a string or as characters:

```
printf("%s\n", M); //print as string

for(i = 0;str[i] != '\0';i++) //print as characters
    {
        printf("%c",str[i]);
    }
```

I want to read a string of 7 characters and store it in M such that afterwards when I print it as a string and as characters I get (assuming the 7 characters entered are: ABCDEFG):

```
ABCDEFG //output of printf("%s\n", M); when printed as string
ABCDEFG abcdabcd //output of the for loop above
```

My answer is:

```
for(K = 0;K<7;K++)
{
  scanf(" %1c", &M[K]);
}
```

but the above doesn't work as it should.

EDIT:

it outputs

```
 ABCDEFGdabcdabcd
```

for both cases.

Comment: "*... but the above doesn't work as it should.*" but does exactly what?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should add a statement:`M[7] = '\0'`. The last character for the string should be '\0'.

Comment: I don't know why people downvote my question and your answer. Weird. Your answer was very helpful.

Comment: @Lisanne: How does this answer meet your requirements: "*... such that afterwards when I print it as a string and as characters I get (assuming the 7 characters entered are: ABCDEFG): `ABCDEFG //output of printf("%s\n", M); when printed as string ABCDEFG abcdabcd //output of the for loop above`*"

Comment: placing his answer below the code scanf(" %1c", &M[K]); gives the correct output, namely ABCDEFG //output of printf("%s\n", M); when printed as string and ABCDEFG abcdabcd //output of the for loop above